# Python AccesControl AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAPI2'

Tags: python

I am receiving the following error when trying to import AccessControl.

```
C:\windows\system32>python
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import AccessControl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AccessControl\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from AccessControl.Implementation import setImplementation
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AccessControl\Implementation.py", line 96, in <module>
    setImplementation("C")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AccessControl\Implementation.py", line 51, in setImplementation
    from AccessControl import ImplC as impl
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\AccessControl\ImplC.py", line 17, in <module>
    from AccessControl.cAccessControl import rolesForPermissionOn
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAPI2'
```

I have tried to reinstalling the library but the problem remains the same.
The only thing I found while searching the error is [this](https://github.com/plone/buildout.coredev/issues/341) page but I did not understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by reinstalling python and all the libraries.